# Can not find the tag library descriptor for “http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core”

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, jstl

I have included this at the very top of my JSP page:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
```

I already placed the JSTL JAR file in the `WEB-INF/lib` directory. But still, the JSP can't resolve the taglib. I get the below error:

> Can not find the tag library descriptor for “http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core”

I am using Eclipse Juno and the project structure is shown below:

[image]

Comment: add the jar file to your classpath

Comment: Are you talking about eclipse not being able to resolve the taglib, or tomcat?

Answer (score 125, accepted):

> Can not find the tag library descriptor for “http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core”

Based on [one of your previous questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13217635/eclipse-juno-ee-cant-detect-external-jar) you're using Tomcat 7. In that case you need JSTL 1.2. However, you've there a `jstl.jar` file while JSTL 1.2 has clearly the version number included like so `jstl-1.2.jar`. The sole filename `jstl.jar` is typical for JSTL 1.0 and 1.1. This version requires a `standard.jar` along in `/WEB-INF/lib` which contains the necessary TLD files. However, in your particular case the `standard.jar` is clearly missing in `/WEB-INF/lib` and that's exactly the reason why the taglib URI couldn't be resolved.

To solve this you must remove the wrong JAR file, download [jstl-1.2.jar](https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/javax/servlet/jstl/1.2/jstl-1.2.jar) and drop it in its entirety in `/WEB-INF/lib`. That's all. You do not need to extract it nor to fiddle in project's *Build Path*.

Don't forget to remove that loose `c.tld` file too. It absolutely doesn't belong there. This is indeed instructed in some poor tutorials or answers elsewhere in the Internet. This is a myth caused by a major misunderstanding and misconfiguration. There is never a need to have a loose JSTL TLD file in the classpath, also not in previous JSTL versions.

In case you're using Maven, use the below coordinate:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

You should also make sure that your `web.xml` is declared conform *at least* Servlet 2.4 and thus not as Servlet 2.3 or older. Otherwise EL expressions inside JSTL tags would in turn fail to work. Pick the highest version matching your target container and make sure that you don't have a `<!DOCTYPE>` anywhere in your `web.xml`. Here's a Servlet 3.0 (Tomcat 7) compatible example:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    version="3.0">

    <!-- Config here. -->

</web-app>
```

###See also:

- [Our JSTL wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info) (you can reach there by hovering the mouse on [jstl](/questions/tagged/jstl) and clicking *info* link)
- [How to install JSTL? The absolute uri: http://java.sun.com/jstl/core cannot be resolved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4928271/how-to-install-jstl-the-absolute-uri-http-java-sun-com-jstl-core-cannot-be-r/)

Comment: just adding jstl-1.2.jar jar solved in my case. Thanks

Answer (score 18):

I had same problem and despite having jstl

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

I had to add 'standard' as well:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
    <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Also, as mentioned in previous post:

- for version 1.0 use: http://java.sun.com/jstl/core
- for 1.1 (and later) use: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core

Answer (score 12):

The URI depends on the version of JSTL you are using. For Version 1.0 use:

```
http://java.sun.com/jstl/core
```

and for 1.1 (and later), you need to use:

```
http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core
```

Comment: Helped me. Thank you

Answer (score 5):

If you are using maven your pom's `<dependencies>` tag should look like:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
        <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

It works for me.

Comment: I have been looking at this issue for years off and on, with all the correct setup which is documented everywhere. Adding taglibs as shown above from https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.taglibs/taglibs-standard-impl/1.2.5 resolved it.

Answer (score 2):

Downloading jstl-1.2.jar instead of jstl.jar solves the problem

Answer (score 2):

This works as well:

```
<dependency>
    <scope>compile</scope>
    <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

so used jstl 1.2 instead of standard.jar together with jstl-api 1.2

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that both the below jars are present in the build path:

1. standard-1.1.2.jar
2. jstl-api-1.2.jar

Maven Dependencies are:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl-api</artifactId>
    <version>$1.2</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
   <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
   <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
   <version>1.1.2</version>
</dependency
```

Comment: unreal when the negative vote, actually is the only one that solves the problem

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure this in web.xml as well:

```
<taglib>
    <taglib-uri>http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core</taglib-uri>
    <taglib-location>/WEB-INF/lib/c.tld</taglib-location>
</taglib>
```

Comment: Whether you need to do this depends on the JSP version in use. This is only neccessary for version smaller than 2.0. Tomcat uses JSP 2.0 since 5.5. So under normal circumstances, this should not be needed.

Comment: Thanks @nfechner..I was not aware of this.

Comment: This bad myth is only true when you used the wrong JSTL version for the JSP version. You should instead rather have downloaded and used the right JSTL version for the JSP version used. You should absolutely not extract the TLD file from the JAR and clutter the classpath and web.xml with it. See also http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info

Answer (score 0):

Well, I have read this post and seems it is not good enough to fix this issue.

Spring based application on the tomcat 8 will not work.

Here is the solution

**Step 1** ⇒ Add the following dependency in your pom.xml

```
<!-- JSTL Support -->

     <dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

**Step 2** ⇒ Add All following two statement in your JSP page, ensure that you are using isELIgnored="false" attribute in <%@ page %> tag

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" isELIgnored="false" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
```

**Step 3** ⇒ Remove all the other configuration that you have done till now in web.xml or anywhere else :)

**Step 4** ⇒ Clean the Tomcat and restart Tomcat.

Side Note ⇒ Actually, JSTL will work with only 3.x Servlet specifications on Tomcat 8.

```
[http://www.kriblog.com/j2ee/jsp/jstl-with-spring-4-on-tomcat-8.html]
```

Comment: Servlet and JSP APIs don't belong in webapp. They are already provided by Tomcat itself.

Answer (score 0):

Add the jstl and standard jar files to your library.

Answer (score 0):

add the maven dependencies:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>jstl</groupId>
  <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
  <version>1.2</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
  <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
  <version>1.1.2</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply download javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.jar and add to your build path and `WEB-INF/lib` if you simply developing dynamic web application.

When you develop dynamic web application using maven then add javax.servlet.jsp.jstl dependency in pom file.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very common error while working on JSTL.

To solve this error simply:

1. Download jstl-1.1.2.jar and standard-1.1.2.jar
2. And then just paste them in lib folder under WEB-INF of your Dynamic Web App project.

Comment: Jstl jar version depends on the version of the Tomcat server

Answer (score 0):

To resolve the issue in jsp we have to use the dependency below in the pom file. If you dont use maven then download the dependency jar and add it to your WEB-INF directory.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>jstl</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
    <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.2</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: The `standard` dependency is not needed at all. You're basically mixing JSTL 1.2 API+impl from Oracle with JSTL 1.1 impl from Apache here. This makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error message (Eclipse Enterprise 2020-06, Tomcat 8.5, dynamic web project), even after I downloaded version 1.2.5 of the jst library ([here](http://tomcat.apache.org/download-taglibs.cgi)), dropped it into the "WEB-INF/lib" folder and added `<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>` to the very top of the jsp file.

Using version 1.2 ([here](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax/servlet/jstl/1.2/jstl-1.2.jar)) instead fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I found sometimes even with the right dependencies, Eclipse can still raise the error. Below are the methods I used to make Eclipse update:

**Method 1 : Copy paste jsp.**

[error happens for jsp in deeper layer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U4F26.png)

I also find a strange situation that when the same jsp is deeper in my directory, its taglibs cannot be found. However, when it is under /webapp/ it has no issue.

I tried maven clean, maven build, project clean, all cannot resolve the problem.

I resolved it by deleting the jsp with error can copy the correct jsp from outer folder to inner folder again. Then the taglibs can be recognized.

[jsp error resolved after copy paste jsp in outer folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mxSlk.png)

Therefore, I think it could be a bug by Eclipse itself.

My dependencies are like

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
        <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

**Method 2 : change version of jstl and change back**

try change version of jstl, then maven clean and maven update, then change back the version and maven clean again.

Comment: The `standard` dependency is not needed at all. You're basically mixing JSTL 1.2 API+impl from Oracle with JSTL 1.1 impl from Apache here. This makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using IntelliJ, download jstl-1.2.jar and standard-1.1.2.jar. Then
add them into your Global Libraries. This worked perfectly for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: The `standard` dependency is not needed at all. You're basically mixing JSTL 1.2 API+impl from Oracle with JSTL 1.1 impl from Apache here. This makes no sense.

Answer (score -1):

What worked for me (I use Java 8 and Tomcat 9 in Eclipse 2019):

**pom.xml**

```
    <!-- jstl -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
        <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

**.jsp file**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Comment: The `standard` dependency is not needed at all. You're basically mixing JSTL 1.2 API+impl from Oracle with JSTL 1.1 impl from Apache here. This makes no sense.