# Eclipse can't find JSP taglibs

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp

I must really be missing something because I have never been able to make Eclipse acknowledge the standard JSP taglibs in any project. Right now, my project has the Dynamic Web Project facet enabled, I can see the `org.apache.taglibs.standard` packages in the classpath, yet the JSP editor keeps saying that it `Can not find the tag library descriptor for "http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/[whatever]"` (core, fmt...).

My `.project` natures are as follows:

```
<natures>
    <nature>org.eclipse.jem.workbench.JavaEMFNature</nature>
    <nature>org.eclipse.wst.common.modulecore.ModuleCoreNature</nature>
    <nature>org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.nature</nature>
    <nature>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javanature</nature>
    <nature>org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.core.jsNature</nature>
</natures>
```

[Here is what my `standard.jar` and its Manifest look like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xxe4X.png)

I found nothing useful on the web on such a simple (and old) matter, it weirds me out. So what am I missing?

Comment: Have you had a look at this yet? It may be related. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13285826/can-not-find-the-tag-library-descriptor-for-http-java-sun-com-jsp-jstl-core

Comment: You might see the class files, but where is the actual .tld file for `http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/[whatever]`?

Comment: @nitind & Lexi I edited my post to add a view of the standard.jar file. Based on the Specification-Version, it seems I use JSTL 1.0.

Comment: Open one of those .tld files. Are you referring to the same URI it declares? The tld files and class files should come from the same version. It just use content assist in the JSP file's taglib URI value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URIs mentionned in the .tld files of the `standard.jar` weren't matching the taglib declarations uri attribute in my JSPs.