# No tag "setDataSource" defined in tag library imported with prefix "sql"

Tags: jstl

I have written the below code in eclipse and running it in Tomcat server.Even though have imported jstl.jar file ,still getting the error :No tag "setDataSource" defined in tag library imported with prefix "sql".Have they removed dataSource from jstl sql?

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    <%@ taglib prefix = "c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix = "sql" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
heklllooo

<sql:setDataSource var = "db" driver = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" 
url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE", user ="system",password = "password"/>

<sql:query var="rs" dataSource = "${db}">select * from Persons</sql:query>
<c:forEach items = "${rs.rows}" var = "person">
<c:out value="${person.personid}"></c:out> : <c:out value="${person.FirstName}"></c:out> 
</c:forEach>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: FYI: the use of JSTL SQL tag library is officially discouraged since 2003 (along with JSTL XML tag library). Make sure you're reading up to date resources when learning JSP/JSTL and not ones dated more than a decade ago or maintained by amateurs instead of authors.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that you have jstl maven dependency in pom.xml and imports are done.

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
   <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
   <version>${jstl.version}</version>
   <scope>runtime</scope>
 </dependency>
```

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13285826/can-not-find-the-tag-library-descriptor-for-http-java-sun-com-jsp-jstl-core) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5987908/how-to-resolve-can-not-find-the-tag-library-descriptor-for-http-java-sun-co) for more clarity.

Answer (score 0):

It's working now.Removed the punctuation marks/comma from the below line and the code is running.